# Special order of a list

Tags: python, list

I have the following problem. It starts with a list which I get. Let's say for example I got the list: `A=['1-00', '10--']` (The list can be longer or even shorter e.g. `B=['01-1', '1-00', '0-01']`). It can also have more entries than four or less. Now I first have to sort for the rank. The rank is defined as the number of digits, that you see.

In A I have one string of rank two `'10--'` and one of rank three `'1-00'`. (In B I have three of rank three) Now I need to get the number of four binary digits numbers which I get with all of the lowest rank strings first.

Here I have only one rank two string `'10--'`I can produce: `'1000', '1001', '1010', '1011'`. So I get **4** binary numbers for rank two. With `'1-00'` I get `'1100'` and `'1000'`. But I already got the second one by the rank two string. So the number I should get is **5** for rank three. That is the number of distinct strings I get with rank two and rank three.

I think its a tough problem but guess there are some commands which I don't know that could help. Hope you can give me some hints :)

Comment: You've described a whole bunch of stuff, but you haven't said what the output your expecting is, or what you've tried so far. Is `A` supposed to change? I think you wanted to sort by rank (which is fairly easy), but it's unclear if you want to do something further, e.g. create a new `list` with all possible expansions for each "wildcarded" pattern. Please update your question to clarify, and let us know what you've tried, and what isn't working.

Comment: You're going to have to explain what these ranks are and how they're determined.

Comment: Is the rank of a string the number of filled-in digits it has?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh You are correct. Sorry, I thought it would be clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to sort by the number of fixed digits ("rank") first, then compute the total number of unique possible bit strings at or below each rank. So for `A`, you'd want it sorted to `['10--', '1-00']` (putting lower rank first), and you'd want to get the number of unique patterns for all rank 2 and lower patterns (in this case, there is only one), then for all rank 3 and lower patterns (again, in this case, only one), etc.

If that understanding is correct, the first step is sorting:

```
A.sort(key=lambda x: x.count('0') + x.count('1'))
# Or if all patterns are of length 4, the slightly simpler:
A.sort(key=lambda x: 4 - x.count('-'))
```

After that, you process by ranks using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), generating unique outputs with [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and storing them in a `set` so you remove duplicates:

```
from __future__ import print_function  # For consistent print on Py2/Py3
from future_builtins import map  # Only on Py2, to get Py3 generator based map

from itertools import groupby, product

uniquebits = set()
for rank, pats in groupby(A, key=lambda x: x.count('0') + x.count('1')):
    for pat in pats:
        # product can be abused to sub 0, then 1 for each wildcarded space
        patpieces = [let if let != '-' else '01' for let in pat]
        # Generate all patterns (using ''.join reduces storage by converting
        # tuples back to str) updating the set to get unique values seen so far
        uniquebits.update(map(''.join, product(*patpieces)))
    print("For rank", rank, "and below,", len(uniquebits), "unique bit strings")
```

Which for your `A` would output:

```
For rank 2 and below, 4 unique bit strings
For rank 3 and below, 5 unique bit strings
```

If you want to avoid gaps, and output for all ranks out to the maximum length of the patterns, it's slightly more complicated (since `groupby` only produces groups when there is at least one input with that "key", in this case, at least one input of a given rank):

```
lastrank = None  # Change to 1 or 2 to force ranks prior to lowest rank to output
for rank, pats in groupby(A, key=lambda x: x.count('0') + x.count('1')):
    if lastrank is not None and lastrank + 1 != rank:
        for fillrank in range(lastrank + 1, rank):
            print("For rank", fillrank, "and below,", len(uniquebits), "unique bit strings")
    lastrank = rank

    for pat in pats:
        # product can be abused to sub 0, then 1 for each wildcarded space
        patpieces = [let if let != '-' else '01' for let in pat]
        # Generate all patterns (using ''.join reduces storage by converting
        # tuples back to str) updating the set to get unique values seen so far
        uniquebits.update(map(''.join, product(*patpieces)))
    print("For rank", rank, "and below,", len(uniquebits), "unique bit strings")

# Or len(max(A, key=len))+1 if uneven lengths
for rank in range(lastrank + 1, len(A[0]) + 1):
    print("For rank", rank, "and below,", len(uniquebits), "unique bit strings")
```

Comment: Wow, I think it works! I will try it for a couple of examples :) One questions: What does this do? `from __future__ import print_function  # For consistent print on Py2/Py3
from future_builtins import map  # Only on Py2, to get Py3 generator based map`

Comment: @HighwayJohn: `print` is a special statement on Py2, and a function on Py3. The first import, if it's the first line of code in the file, means Py2 will use the function from Py3 (means my code works identically on both). Similarly, as a minor optimization, Py3's `map` avoids creating a `list` of results that will be thrown away after the elements are added to the `set`, by generating them one at a time as `set.update` requests them; the second import will make Py2 use that form of `map` instead of creating a `list` of results that is used for the `update` and immediately discarded.

Comment: Okay, I am not sure if I understand it. If I try to run it is says: `ImportError: No module named 'future_builtins'` So I just deleted this line and then it gives me the correct results. Could any problem occure by doing that?

Comment: Actually one moe thing. If the length is 4, then it should also go up until rank 4, which would also 5 unique bit strings. Is there an easy fix? Thanks again a lot!!

Comment: @HighwayJohn: As written, it will only print for ranks where at least one pattern has that rank. If you need it to print for ranks that don't exist (so the unique bit string count output would be identical to the previous rank), you can tweak the code to detect gaps or premature ending. e.g. if you just need to cover ranks after the final rank printed (not gaps), you can just add a final loop after the main loop `for rank in range(rank+1, max(A, key=len)+1): print(...same as main loop print...)` (if all patterns have the same length, the `max` call can simplify to `len(A[0])+1`).

Comment: @HighwayJohn: On `future_builtins`, like I said, that's only on Py2 (sadly, unlike `__future__`, it doesn't just get ignored on Py3, so you need to omit it if running on Py3, or wrap it in a `try`/`except ImportError: pass` if you're expecting to run the same codebase on both Py2 and Py3.

Comment: Ah okay, there shouldn't be any gaps! Not only after the final rank.That is quite important. Otherwise I could produce false results :/  Could you fix that? At the moment I am trying to implement your last answer but so far unsuccessful. That are quite elaborated commands which I dont understand so quickly.. Im sorry for that

Comment: @HighwayJohn: Edited to add hackish approach to filling gaps (I made a mistake in the comment using `max` which is fixed in answer).

Comment: Okay wow, thank you a lot for helping me so quickly. I owe you one :)